# Generate a random variable with a defined correlation to an existing variable(s) considering copula

Tags: correlation, joint-distribution, copula

In [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/444039/%5D) it has been described how to generate a random variable with a defined correlation to an existing variable. My question is what happens if I want to have a specific pattern of correlation, meaning having a copula connecting the two variables. For example if the two variables are normally distributed then it comes up a normal copula. But what if I want to have the two random variables normally distributed but connected with a student T copula. How the answer in [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/444039/%5D)   be generalised to that case.

Comment: If the desired correlation is compatible with a $t$ copula, the explanation is the same.

Comment: I do not understand the comment. How you introduce in the explanation the copula? Could you be more specific?