# Prove that P = A†A is orthogonal projection where A† is pseudo-inverse of A

Tags: matrix, svd

I am new to this but I was wondering how to prove this. I can reduce A†A to (VΣ†UT)(UΣVT). Would I have to reduce the UT and U to the identity matrix and just continue to simplify? I would get something like (VΣT)...(ΣVT), I guess I need help doing a full simplification of A†A

Comment: Your reduction of $A^\dagger A$ is incorrect.  See my analysis at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/444058/919 for a correct expression.

Answer (score 1):

To start with, as you say, $U^TU$ is the identity. That gives you
$$A^\dagger A=V\Sigma^\dagger\Sigma V^T$$
Now, $\Pi=\Sigma^\dagger\Sigma$ is a diagonal matrix with 0s and 1s on the diagonal, so $V\Pi V^T$ is the eigendecomposition of a projection matrix.